# why state is not updated after button click in setinterval react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me why state is not updated ? On button click I updated the state but when I console my state on setinterval  it is not updated why ?

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-shamir-8lmpo[image]

```
 <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState({
            filters: {
              apps: "DDDDDDH",
              searchText: "12333",
              taskType: "",
              dateFrom: "",
              dateTo: "",
              status: ""
            }
          });
        }}
      >


useEffect(() => {
    console.log("===============");
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(state);
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
```

`After button click  searchText: "12333",` searchtext should be `12333` in state but it is showing empty wny ?

why the value of state in `setinterval` is not showing `12333`

Comment: I think (note: I might be wrong) it's because with each render you get a new copy of that useEffect so it will always point to the state _of that render_. Instead of having a settimeout, why not just log when the `searchText` changes instead: `useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state.searchText])`?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself. Linking to off-site services is discouraged.

Comment: @Andy ..I want to do `polling` .in my application .so  I am hitting a service at regular interval of time ..

Comment: but requirement is when I `setstate` then next call will go with updated value

Comment: my `Api` is to `get value` from server.if first case `searchText` is empty and in `secondStep` after button click it send `search Text` value on server to get data

Comment: This may help: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: You shouldn't be able to have State/setState and hooks in the same component, either it's functional and you use hooks, or it's a class and you use state

Comment: @JamesMorrison you can do `const [state, setState] = useState({})`

Comment: @Clarity ah yeah, good shout - OP needs more code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, 10000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [state]);
```